# swiftuiのvideoplayerでmacのデスクトップなどのローカルパスのビデオファイルを再生する方法を知りたい

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

swiftuiでmacos用のvideoplayerを作っています。
"https~"から始まるurlにはアクセスできますが、ローカルパスをfile:///~のurlで打ち込んでも動画が再生できません。
NSOpenPanelを使った場合はローカルパスにアクセスできますが、直接打ち込んで再生できるようにしたいです。

```swift
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var videoUrl: String = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"

//    var videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users~.mp4")
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .onAppear(){
                player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoUrl)!)
            }
    }
}
```

@zunda

回答ありがとうございます。
NSOpenPanelを使って選択したファイルのボタンリストを作り、選択してみました。
imageの方は任意のファイルを表示できますがビデオはやはり読み込めません。

```swift
   @State private var ContentsList : [String] = []
   @State var ContentName = "content"
   @State var player = AVPlayer()
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           if ContentsList.isEmpty == false{
               HStack{
                   AsyncImage(url: URL(string: ContentName)){ image in
                       image.resizable()
                   }placeholder: {
                       ProgressView()
                   }
                   VideoPlayer(player: player)
                       .onAppear() {
                           player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: ContentName)!)
                       }
               }
           }
           
           HStack{
               Button("select item"){
                   let panel = NSOpenPanel()
                   panel.canChooseDirectories = true
                   panel.canChooseFiles = true
                   panel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
                   panel.allowedFileTypes = ["jpg","jpeg","png","mp4","mov"]
                   panel.message = "open files"
                   if panel.runModal() == .OK{
                       for url in panel.urls{
                           ContentsList.append(url.absoluteString)
                       }
                   }
               }
               List(ContentsList, id: \.self){ item in
                   let path = NSString(string: String(item))
                   Button(path.lastPathComponent){
                       ContentName = String(item)
                   }
               }
               .frame(width: 400,height: 300)
               Text(ContentName)
           }
       }
       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`file://`を先頭につけることでうまくいかないですか？

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///Users/okd/Desktop/okdtest.mp4")

  var body: some View {
      let player = AVPlayer(url: filePath)
      VideoPlayer(player: player)
  }
}
```

Comment: file:///を先頭につけてみましたが動画を読み込んでくれません。

Comment: このURLの指定の仕方だとファイルパスが間違えていました。
`URL.userDirectory.appending(path: "okd/Desktop/okdtest.mp4")`が正しいものでした。

しかし権限周りで、ダメそうです。NSOpenPanel経由だと権限が与えられているのかもしれません。

Comment: 一度NSOpenPanelで開くと権限が与えられて、再度コードでURL指定しても再生できるので、NSOpenPanelで何かされてますね。